# marking a radio input as slected when page is loaded

Tags: html

I have two radio buttons. I want one of them to be shown as selected when the page loads. Which property I should use, and how?

Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="musictype2" value="rock" default> Rock<br>
<input type="radio" name="musictype2" value="alternative"> Alternative<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="genreselect" value="rock" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="genreselect" value="alternative" />
```

In this case "rock" is preselected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2" checked="checked" />test
```

like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use the `checked` attribute:

```
<input type=radio name="my_name" VALUE="my_value" checked />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="genre" value="rock" checked /> Rock<br />
    <input type="radio" name="genre" value="alternative" /> Alternative
</form>
```

This is the correct way. The name attribute needs to be the same in order for them to switch between.

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WQxmx/).